# Streaming video file from home computer to website hosted externally

Tags: video-streaming

Streaming video file from home computer to website hosted externally, basically i want to be able to have someone put file://(myip:dontknowifportisneeded)/videos/garfield.mp4 sort of thing into their web browser and for it to access it on my home computer any help on how?

Comment: I would like to give you a better answer, but I have some questions about this. 
Is there a reason not to use existing video sharing services?
Is your computer running Windows/Linux/Mac?
Are you able to open ports for your computer in your router?

Comment: I expanded my answer with a specific solution for you, assuming you are using Windows on your computer. Let me know if you need further help with port-forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you would need to setup a "Web Server" on your computer and forward the necessary ports to it from within your router.
Then you could serve files publicly over the internet from your home computer.

How you do that specifically depends on the operating system you are running (i.e. Windows/Linux/Mac) and what is available for it.

#### Assuming you are running Windows...

...you might take a look at [Mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose). *(Not to be confused with the MongoDB library of the same name.)*

They have a purpose built binary available here: https://mongoose.ws

[Here is the link to the binary directly: https://mongoose.ws/downloads/mws/mongoose.exe](https://mongoose.ws/downloads/mws/mongoose.exe)

And the generic instructions for setup:

```
1. Create a new folder C:\mongoose
2. Right-click on the download button
3. Choose "Save As", save to C:\mongoose folder
4. Double-click on exe to start (minimises to a tray icon)
5. Right-click on a tray icon to change settings
```

You can modify those instructions and put mongoose in whatever folder you want.
In your case, I would create a folder with the video(s) you want to share inside of it and put the `mongoose.exe` you download inside of that folder; instead of creating `C:\mongoose` folder.

Once you have your folder setup and `mongoose.exe` is inside of it, double-click it to start.

You should see the tray icon appear in the bottom right "Notification Area".

Right-click on that icon to see the program menu. Select "Go to local URL" and you should see a directory index showing mongoose, and your videos or any other files you put in the folder.

If that is all working, now you need to access your router configuration in order to forward `mongoose` on to public internet (so your friend can access it, too).

The steps to do this will vary depending on your home setup and router model.
But, as far as I can tell, you only need to forward port 8000 from your local machine for this to work.

Once you have the port forwarded, your friend should be able to visit `http://YOUR-PUBLIC-IP:8000` and access that directory.

#### If you are running Linux...

...you can pick it up through [github](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose). Depending on your distro I would suggest getting it through your package manager.

In Fedora you can open a terminal and do:

`dnf install mongoose`

In Debian it is there through:

`apt install mongoose`

I imagine you could get it through Ubuntu in the additional repos, or in a similar fashion for any respective distribution.
There is also a [linux binary](https://mongoose.ws/downloads/mws/mongoose_linux) available alongside the windows binary, however it did not work for me with the given instruction. [On this page.](https://mongoose.ws)

Once you have the working binary or package installed, you should be able to run something like this in the terminal:

`mongoose -r /var/www -s /etc/cert.pem -p 8080,8043s`

*Start serving files from /var/www. Listen on port 8080 for HTTP, and 8043 for HTTPS connections. Use /etc/cert.pem as SSL certificate file.*
[Example taken from the Mongoose man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mongoose)

For your use case you could simplify it to something like:

`mongoose -r /home/youruser/folderwithvideostoshare/ -p 8080`

And then forward out port 8080 on your router.
At that point you should be able to visit http://YOUR-IP:8080 and see the files.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks a bunch, how would i go about it if my os is linux?

Comment: Ah even better to do it with linux, and many more options. I will update the guide for mongoose, shortly. But there are MANY webserver solutions available on linux. You will still need to forward the right ports for whatever you set up, though.

Comment: Added some direction for linux usage. Please feel free to upvote the answer if it helps. =) Cheers!